# Hiding a custom field if no value is submitted

Tags: php, custom-fields, isnull

How can I hide a specific field on a page displaying data from a form if no value is submitted? An example is below:

```
<?php if($price): ?>
<li><?php echo $price;?>: <?php echo get_property_price($post->ID);?>&nbsp;<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'rentperiod',true);?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't want the `$price` or `rentperiod` values to display as a list item if they are empty. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use `if(isset($price))` instead.

Comment: Please follow instructions at http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the data first, then display it conditionally.  Also avoid changing too often between php and html to get more readable code.
Use the variable expansion in double quotes strings.

```
$property_price = get_property_price($post->ID);
$rentperiod = get_post_meta($post->ID,'rentperiod',true);

if($price && ($property_price || $rentperiod)) 
    echo "<li>$price: $property_price&nbsp;$rentperiod</li>";
```

Comment: Thank you Lorenz, that did what I was looking for!. So what this is essentially saying is if there is no price input, then do not show the label or the field associated with it?

Comment: @andrew Is $price just the label ? If this is the case I have to adapt my code. $price is really not a good name for a label !

Comment: No, sorry, $price is not the label. It's pulling the label from somewhere else... this is code from a template so I am not too knowledgeable on how the original developer designed this, but its working as I intended now with your guidance.